# Quickly resolving GIT merge conflict with --theirs

Tags: git, github, merge

I have a branch called 'feature_game_rooms'. I would like to merge this branch into master. I basically want master to be an exact copy of feature_game_rooms. Heres what I've tried
1. `git checkout master`
2. `git merge feature_game_rooms` ---> results in Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result. 
3. `git add .`
4. `git checkout --theirs .`
This resulted in a compilation errors though because the conflict markers are still in my files.
Heres what git status looks like after `git merge feature_game_rooms`:
[image]

Comment: Did you try `git merge recursive theirs`?

Comment: No. When I `git merge recursive theirs feature_game_rooms` it says "merge: not something we can merge"

Comment: You should reset all first back to original master

Comment: ya I did a `git reset --hard` before trying the code

Answer (score 8):

With help from Lol4t0's comment, I looked into merging recursively with the the `theirs` option. Heres what I did:
1. `git checkout master`
2. `git merge -Xtheirs feature_game_rooms` --> still 1 conflict because branch deleted a file that master has
3. `git add .` <-- removes file
Heres a [link](http://miguelcamba.com/blog/2013/04/24/git-tip-merge-branches-taking-always-changes-from-one-of-them/) that helped me out